# Custom role to link PDF file as static content

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx, static-files

I am trying to write a custom role for Sphinx to allow linking to PDF files that are then displayed in the browser (rather than being downloaded when using the `:download:` role).

I have got as far as a role that creates a link to the PDF file:

```
:pdf:`Document Title <pdf/document.pdf>`
```

generates something like:

```html
<a href="pdf/document.pdf>Document Title</a>
```

However, I don't know how to get Sphinx to copy the `pdf` directory to the output directory.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`html_static_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path) in your `conf.py`.

```py
html_static_path = ['_static', 'pdf']
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution I had come up with. I was hoping my custom role code could copy the files to a 'pdf' directory in the output. But maybe it's not worth worrying about