# Having Sphinx copy to the install location images referenced only in raw commands not explicitly in rst?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have some raw code in my rst that links to images in the images directory in my repository. But since Sphinx does not directly know about these images it does not copy them over to the Sphinx install directory so the resulting HTML (that contains the raw) cannot find them. The exact details are

mydirectory/images/image1.png mydirectory/images/image2.png
mydirectory/mypage.rst

mypage.rst contains

..:image: images/image.png
..:raw: <img src="_images/image2.png"

Run Sphinx, it generates an install directory which contains

installdir/mypage.html and
installdir/_images/image1.png

That is, it copies image/image1.png to installdir/_images/image1.png

Is there a way to tell Sphinx to also copy image/image1.png to installdir/_images/image1.png ? The reason I need Spinx to do the copy is that when run on ReadTheDocs ReadTheDocs works directly with conf.py and I cannot add external linux calls to copy the images/image2.png.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom role to link PDF file as static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215666/custom-role-to-link-pdf-file-as-static-content)

Comment: No, it is not what I was hoping for.  When you have ..:image: images/image.png then Sphinx makes a copy of the file in the installation directory _images/image.png  and the installed generated .HTML files can link to them with a https reference. I would like to list additional files in images that sphinx also automatically copies over to _images in the install directory. Thanks.

Comment: @BarrySmith: Please edit the question and add the exact requirements that you mention in the comment. And show us your "raw code".

Comment: You could try the `html_extra_path` option (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_extra_path). It does not work exactly like you want but maybe it's good enough.